# Build QuerySet that is not related to any model instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
from django.db import models


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('title', max_length=100)


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('title', max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField('body')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

How can I build a QuerySet that selects all tags that are not related to any blog post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
tags = Tag.objects.filter(post__isnull=True)
```

You can read more on [lookups that span multivalued relationships here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships)